# store data in tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent

how can i store data to database in tables

i have two tables in my migration

I want to save the "firstName" to "usersAppointments" table but, it always trying to save the data to "appointments" table

"I'm Beginner"

MIGRATION

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('appointments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('');
            $table->string('');        
            $table->date('');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('usersAppointments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('firstName');       
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

CONTROLLER

```
            public function store(Request $request){
                
                $data = $request->validate([
                    '' => 'required',
                    '' => 'required',            
                    '' => 'required'
                ]);
        
                Appointment::create($data);
                return redirect('/');
            }

           public function usersAppointment(Request $request){
                
                $data = $request->validate([
                    'firstName' => 'required'               
                ]);
        
                Appointment::create($data);
                return redirect('/');
```

MODEL

```
    protected $fillable = [
        '', '', '',
        'firstName'
    ];
```

Comment: How are you hitting the method `usersAppointment`?

Comment: You're using `Appointment::create($data);` in `usersAppointment`; that will insert data to the `appointments` table. You would need another model, or a relationship to save to the `usersAppointments` table (note: that should be `users_appointments`, or `appointment_user`, etc. to follow naming conventions). Do you have a `UserAppointment` model?

Answer (score 0):

That's because of trying to insert the data into 'Appointment'.

you must write the code as below :

```
public function usersAppointment(Request $request){
    
    $data = $request->validate([
        'firstName' => 'required'               
    ]);

    UsersAppointment::create($data);
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: Yes you're right that's my mistake,  I had edit my answer